# NZEC error in Python spoj

Tags: python

Please have a look at my code and tell me where I am going wrong.
I am trying to solve a problem on SPOJ and the online judge gives me a runtime error (NZEC)

I am trying to solve this problem - http://www.spoj.com/problems/PRIME1/

```
def isprime(n):
  if n < 2:
    return 1
  if n == 2 or n == 3:
    return 0
  if n % 2 == 0 or n % 3 == 0:
    return 1
  for i in range(5, int(n ** 0.5) + 1, 6):
    if n % i == 0 or n % (i + 2) == 0:
      return 1
  return 0

t = int(raw_input())
for i in range(0,t):
  m = int(raw_input())
  n = int(raw_input())
  for j in range(m,n+1):
    if isprime(j) == 0:
      print j
  print
```

Comment: `import sys` and add `sys.exit(0)` at the end of your code

Comment: You need to describe what it should do and what it does. If it's a compile error, what is it? How are you testing it and what test data does it fail on. Your question is currently too broad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my experience `NZEC` just means some exception along the way. Most likely input-related.

For example my input for the problems looks like:

```
t = int(raw_input())
data = sys.stdin.readlines()
for line in data:
    n, m = map(int, line.split())
```

And indeed `raw_input` gets the whole line, which you're trying to convert to `int`. But the problem states both `m` and `n` are on the same line:

```
Input:
2
1 10
3 5
```